# Python: How to stop a thrift server programmatically?

Tags: python, server, thrift

I just would like to stop/close a thrift TSimpleServer created with python. However, no .stop() and .close() can do this due to the error "AttributeError: 'TSimpleServer' object has no attribute 'stop'." Is there any solution can solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.transport import TTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from thrift.server import TServer
from rpc1_nodejs_call_python import printService

from TestHandler import TestHandler

processor = printService.Processor(TestHandler())
transport = TSocket.TServerSocket(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
tfactory = TTransport.TBufferedTransportFactory()
pfactory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory()
server = TServer.TSimpleServer(processor, transport, tfactory, pfactory)

print("Starting thrift server in python...")
server.serve()

print("Stoping thrift server in python...")
server.stop()
# server.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it seems not possible/foreseen at all:
https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/py/src/server/TServer.py

As you noticed, there is no `stop()` and all three servers implementations currently loop endlessly  `while true`.

The usual approach, assumed someone would be going to add this, would be to have a `stop()` method which sets some flag or the like to indicate termination. The call to it must be made from another thread, since the first one is still kept inside `serve()` while serving.

Bottom line: Seems not implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What flags signals can be used to notify  the termination by another thread? There seems no related detection in the endless loop.

Comment: Exactly "*Bottom line: Seems not implemented yet*" ... but we accept pull requests :-)